# Thread 1: "+[UIImage systemImageNamed:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x111e616e0"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, uiimageview

**Thread 1: "+[UIImage systemImageNamed:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x111e616e0"**

This error occurs in app delegate when trying to run my application in iOS 12 iphone 6s but its working normally in iOS 13+ devices  [Error text shown in XCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuN76.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The reason behind crash is SFSymbol is only available on iOS 13 and above version.

```
UIImage(systemName: "") -> It will crash on iOS 12 and below version.
```

If you want to use SFsymbol in iOS 12 and below version then check this URL

[How to use SF Symbols in iOS 12 and below?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56449218/how-to-use-sf-symbols-in-ios-12-and-below)